# Proper Implementation of Grid Splitter for User Defined Element Height in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

I am trying to implement a grid with a grid splitter and I want to make the upper and lower row of the grid resize up and down. The first row of the grid consists of two parts: a data grid and a stack panel containing further elements. The stack panel should always stay the same size but the data grid should always fill the available space.
All elements are declared vertically strechable.

Problem nr. 1: If I put the entire first row in a stack pannel, the data grid is being automatically schrinked to MinHeight, but I want to have a predfined default height, and only the user can shrink the first row to a its minimal height. In other words, when the program is strated the grid splitter is on its default position and the data grid in the upper part fills the available space even if there is no content in it.  If I define the "Height" parameter, the data grid is not being resized when the grid splitter is moved.

Problem nr. 2 The lower part of the view (the third row) contains a text box which is dynamically filled  (something like a console window). Because it is vertically strechable, the thrid row starts streching down as the text box is filled instead of staying the same height - the one that user defines by moving the grid splitter up and down.

Any ideas on how to solve these problems?

**First problem solution**:  I have solved the first problem by using the DockPanel instead of StackPanel. I have set the data grid to be the bottom element (a kind of a trade-off, it was upper before but it is also good as a lower element). I have done the same with the TabControl in the second row. However, I have the problem nr.2 in upper and lower row. No matter where user sets the grid splitter, the elements expand when the content is added dynamically. How can I make the elements stay the same height even if more content is added (scroll bar should appear in this case)?

This is my new code:

```
        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
            <!-- New Job setup-->
            <StackPanel Height="40" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10"  Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
              <!-- a few labels and text boxes go here -->
            </StackPanel>

            <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0" MinHeight="50"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      >
            </DataGrid>

        </DockPanel>

        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" Height="5" Grid.Row="1"/>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">
            <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                ContentTemplateSelector= "{StaticResource selector}" SelectedItem="{Binding FocusedTab}">

                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                 ........
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Post the XAML you have tried.

Comment: There, I hope that helps

Comment: You don't post the TextBlock on the 3rd row so can't help you there but if that is moving the splitter then you have a layout problem.  Try a default MinHeight for the DataGrid.  Handle the Splitter DragEnter and change the MinHeight the first time only.

Comment: The third row is actually complicated because the TabControl has two different templates: one with the datagrid and one with a text block. The tab with the text block is always visible, but the tab with a data grid is visible on demand.  This is the template code for the text box:     <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  IsReadOnly="True"                      ut:TextBoxBehavior.ScrollOnTextChanged="True"/>

    </Grid>